# do anonymous-function take more memory in loop

Tags: c#, anonymous-function

I was wondering. Does the following code snippet consume more memory than the second

```
List<Action> myList = new List<Action>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
   myList.Add(() => { /* Code */});
}
```

This time, I point to a method.

```
List<Action> myList = new List<Action>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
   myList.Add(myFuntion);
}

void myFuntion()...
```

I was wondering if the first code snippet uses more memory because it has to store the anonymous method. Or is it pointing to the same anonymous function every time

And does the second code snippet point to the function or does it store the whole function every time

Thanks

Comment: Generally the compiler will generate a delegate for your lambda - at runtime it's no different to an ordinary method... there may be some exceptions here though.

Comment: go to Analyze > Performance Profiler > Tick Memory Usage > Start > Take snapshot > end program and see results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell for .NET for sure but in general it depends if the anonymous function captures any element from the surrendering function (e.g. `myList` in your example) or not. If not in can be changed by the compiler into a normal static function with a compiler-generated name.

If it captures something then the compiler has to generate and allocate an extra datastructure which stores the captured variables and uses this as an argument to the compiler-generated function. E.g. if you do `myList.Add(() => { var z = myList.Count; .... });` the compiler needs to generate something like this for it:

```
class GenertedEnv
{
    public List<Action> myList;
}

static void AnonymousFunction(GeneratedEnv env, /* Plus other lambda parameters*/)
{
    var z = env.myList.Count;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Even in the case of closures, the compiler generates a class that contains members for the closed variables (and keeps them updated for you) - see [here](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsB0AZSBHAbgChRJZEUNMBhAewBt7UBjZMWiETAcVQlQBOYZsVLR4SNOmJEADsABG9YTGb0AhiBAwAYrVowA3kSIwzMeUpUp1bZjAButMABMYAWXWQAFAEojRACQgbgoADwAgqzsEAB8MOgIocgwALww/ADuMMmR0RyxfsTBAGa0At6QKWBpMAAMBDA1YTAAjHUdDU0A1N2+QYHG5sGBicmYES4u3n5p8YYwdJwMqJgA6kJouPzeAEQAcsDoCoIwuzDdTb4EAL7XAzdBjzdAA==). There's no "runtime method generation" involved.

Comment: A [better example](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsB0AZSBHAbgChRJZEUNMBhAewBt7UBjZMWiETAcVQlQBOYZsVLR4SNOmJEADsABG9YTGb0AhiBAwAYrVowA3kSIwzMeUpUp1bZjAButMABMYAWXWQAFAEojRACQgbgoADwAgqzsEAB8MOgIocgwALww/ADuMMmR0RyxfsTBAGa0At6QKWBpMAAMBDA1YTAAjHUdDU0A1N2+QYHG5sMjDuoCMAAetWDE5sGBicmYES4u3n5p8YYwdJwMqJgA6kJouPzeAEQAcsDoCoIwlzDdU74EAL7vpiO/P7/DSa9YqBD5BMEfIA=) that demonstrates how the class members are updated when variable values change.

Comment: I wanted to say here that the compiler generates the class and function, not that it's generated at runtime. But yes, the decompiled code from your link helps to visualize what the compiler really does here.

Comment: yes, what I was getting at is that the structure is still generated for actions with closures but I misread your post and now realise that you addressed that also.

Answer (score 2):

The first method will create an inner class with a method and assign that method to the `Action` delegate you're adding to the list.
However, it appears it will only instantiate one Action and add that to the list every time.
Source: [tryroslyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcNSVolDAOgGEB7AGwtQGNkwyIQiBxVCVAJzBswCgADsABGFHjBoUAhiBAwSMAN58YqmENHiAbmTAATGAFkAFAEoVa5WuswAMmBQAeAIJ0GEAHwx0CeyhgAvDAcAO52DsguboweZvw2agBmZJzGkMgwYIEwAAzYWY4wAIw5pXmZANQV5gmqVrVqPn7IRM56esZmgV6K8owglKhEAOrcaPYcxgBEzhCMCOhkoN6oyAAWZHpTptgAvjsWCbuHMMfWJxpiNDA6+jAAcmYn9QnNUfQx3r4R2aHhTq4Pp44idrMlODA0hAMlkguUCsUyvCqjVai8Gk0Iq12sZDAgAGLACDRCAHBpnNQU1QnW4GPGE4lArq9chMQYjMaoCaoab0okk7Z7E58XZAA===)

The second method is equivalent to

```
list.Add(new Action(MyFunction));
```

so it will instantiate a new Action in every loop.

You can test it and see the 1st method will instantiate only one Action:
[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3rzDC1)
It can be quite surprising sometimes to discover what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: So the second way is slower ?

Comment: @CodeJoy It would appear so. I didn't know it did this either. I expected both methods to be in essence the same. (Something went wrong when copying the tryroslyn link. Fixed now. It also found it doesn't work on all browsers)